# why "bcl 20, 31, $+4" instructoin for obtaining the address of next instruction in LR? why not "bl $+4" or "bcl 20, xx, $+4"?

Tags: powerpc

I have read the last Power ISA manual from IBM (https://openpowerfoundation.org/?resource_lib=power-isa-version-3-0) and says [in page 35; 2.4 Branch Instructions]:

> Obtaining the address of the next instruction:Use the following form of Branch and Link.
>
> `bcl 20, 31, $+4`

where this *standard* comes from? It appears in all manual of powerpc instruction set, but there is some reason for write that?

In fact, the GNU compiler use that instruction.

Comment: My question really is: why that instruction? Instead for instance 'bl $+4'

Answer (score 3):

Because on Power the instruction pointer isn't a general register we use this trick to get it into the LR.

$+4 is the next instruction which we jump to.

20 - corresponds in binary to 10100 which in Figure 40 means branch always.

31 is a condition register - which is ignored because of branch always.

So with this instruction we end up at the next instruction, and as a side effect we have LR containing the instruction address (of the instruction after the branch).

LR is effectively a return address (p.37 the `if LK then LR <- CIA + 4` text) of the "subroutine" we just called (and don't need to return from. In Power this is used as a quick form compared to the stack).